# Perl - How to remove a matched line AND "x" lines surrounding a match in a file

Tags: perl, file-io

I have a sitemap.xml file that is appended by my script (The script makes static pages from my dynamic site and adds the static pages url to the sitemap.)

But, there is a case where I need the script to delete the (5) lines when the $SomeID page is no longer needed.

Here is an example of a section of the sitemap I want to delete when the $SomeID (12345 for example) is matched:

```
     <url>
        <loc>http://mydomain.com/directory/some-page-name-34-098765.htm</loc>
        <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
        <priority>0.5</priority>
        </url>
#I want to delete from here
     <url> 
        <loc>http://mydomain.com/directory/some-page-name-340-12345.htm</loc>
        <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
        <priority>0.5</priority>
        </url>
##to here (when 12345 is matched (done below))
     <url>
        <loc>http://mydomain.com/directory/some-page-name-445-45673.htm</loc>
        <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
        <priority>0.5</priority>
        </url>
```

Now, I can find the line and its' number:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use CGI;
use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser warningsToBrowser);
print CGI::header();
use strict;
use warnings;
use LWP::Simple qw(!head);
use Fcntl; #needed for the verbose file handler calls like O_CREAT
use File::Slurp;
use File::Basename;
use DBI;
use Tie::File;
```

ABOVE is an EXAMPLE of modules I have used in the past for various reasons.

Not needed to run below but, just pasted in from another script.

```
my $SiteMapFile = 'sitemap.xml';
my $fh;
my $SomeID='12345'; 
my $cnt = '1';
my @SiteMap;


    open($fh, "<", $SiteMapFile ) || die "Can't open $SiteMapFile: $!";
    my @maplines = <$fh>;
    foreach(@maplines){
    if ($_ =~ $SomeID){
    print qq~Match in sitemap Sitemap Line $_<br />~;
    push(@SiteMap, $_);
    print qq~Found match at line number $cnt<br />;
    }
    $cnt++;
    }
    close $fh;
```

I pushed the matching line into the array for the next step I guess.

Is there a way I can delete a line by its' line number?

So, I can delete the line, the line before it and the 3 lines after it WITHOUT creating a temp file / using two files?

I looked at some similar posts here but, nothing nailed my problem or explained it down to my point of comprehension.

I am pretty much a noob but, patient.
(Forgive my basic coding skills above?)
I gave up so, here I am!

Thanks...

(I can use modules like Tie::File if needed)

Comment: This looks like XML. Can't you parse it with some standard module to usual array of hashes structure and work on it instead of regexps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, easiest would be, if you stored `$cnt` in an array whenever you find the evil Id, say that array is called `@badLines`. That way you would have all the line numbers that need deleting around them. Then you need a loop like:

```
my $index=0;
foreach(@badLines)
{
    splice (@maplines, $_-1-($index*5), 5); # Remove 5 lines starting one before the offending one.
    $index++;
}
```

http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/splice.html

And then you would just print `@maplines` back to your file.

edit: I forgot about how the indizes shift down whenever a splice is done. The above edit should handle that but is way less nice looking. One could of course try to iterate through the array in reversed order to get past the index shiftig problem.

Comment: That looks promising, I am off to try.

Comment: JFYI, after the first `splice` all the next lines will shift down to new indices.

Comment: Wow, splice! However, I had to change to -2 for some reason.

Comment: @Oleg V. Volkov: Ohhh, i straight up forgot that. I will correct my answer, thanks for the heads up.

Comment: @DeVadder, IMO cleanest solution is to sort offending line numbers and iterate in descending order - you won't have to remember offset that way.

Answer (score 1):

This will keep all data within  tags in a temp variable. When another  is encountered, it checks if the temp variable contains the someID. If it doesn't, then it pushes the row in the @SiteMap array. In the end, you only need to print the contents of the @SiteMap to your new file. It is not exactly what you asked, but it makes more sense to use the  open tag, instead of counting rows.

```
my $SiteMapFile = 'sitemap.xml';
my $fh;
my $SomeID='12345'; 
my $cnt = 1;
my @SiteMap;


open($fh, "<", $SiteMapFile ) || die "Can't open $SiteMapFile: $!";
my @maplines = <$fh>;
my $tmprow;
foreach my $line(@maplines){
  if ($line =~ /<url>/){
    push @SiteMap, $tmprow if ($tmprow !~ /$SomeID/);
    $tmprow = $line;
  } else {
    $tmprow .= $line."\n";
  }
  $cnt++;
}
close $fh;
#dont forget to check the last element
push @SiteMap, $tmprow if ($tmprow !~ /$SomeID/);

print join("\n", @SiteMap);
```

Comment: I might be very tired. But this appears to never get to push anything to me. It only gets to the push if `$line` matches <url> but only pushes if `$line` matches `$SomeID`... I suppose it is actually `$tmprow` that needs NOT to match `$SomeID` for the pushing to take place.

Answer (score 1):

It is really very messy and difficult to munge XML as strings. It might seem easier than some of the modules at first but once you get past the learning curve, the parser/writer approach is better on every level.

Here is an approach that will allow more flexibility and guarantee you end up with valid XML. Docs: [XML::LibXML](https://metacpan.org/module/XML%3a%3aLibXML), [XML::LibXML::XPathContext](https://metacpan.org/module/XML%3a%3aLibXML%3a%3aXPathContext).

```
use XML::LibXML;
use XML::LibXML::XPathContext;

my $doc = XML::LibXML->new->parse_fh(\*DATA);
my $xc  = XML::LibXML::XPathContext->new($doc);
$xc->registerNs( sitemap => $doc->documentElement->namespaceURI );

for my $loc ( $xc->findnodes('//sitemap:loc') )
{
    # Up to you to make the match/check sane and robust.
    $loc->parentNode->unbindNode
        if $loc->textContent =~ /\b 12345 \b/x;
}

print $doc->toString(1);

__DATA__
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9 http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
-- snipped your URLs for space --
</urlset>
```